Como podría usar el winfo_exists en este código? u otra manera de resolver mi problema?
necesito ayuda en este código, quiero que si le doy a un botón y hay algo dentro del frame se destruya, ósea que se previamente le doy al botón de operaciones cuando le de al de conversiones no se superponga si no que se destruya el anterior y se coloque el nuevo, lo mismo al revés.
def operaciones():
    
    

    frame_calculos=customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=a,fg_color="#f0f0f0", height= 350)
    frame_calculos.pack(pady=10, padx= 15, fill= "both", expand= True) 

    
    a.geometry("500x600")


    entry_comple = customtkinter.CTkEntry(frame_calculos, border_color="#f0f0f0")
    entry_comple.pack()
    entry_comple.place(x=255, y=75)

    primer_num = customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame_calculos, text="Primer numero", text_color="#000000",font=("Arial", 22))                                           
    primer_num.pack()
    primer_num.place(x=25, y=10)



def convercion():

    frame_calculos1=customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=a,fg_color="#f0f0f0", height= 350)
    frame_calculos1.pack(pady=10, padx= 15, fill= "both", expand= True)



    a.geometry("500x570")

        boton_exponencial=customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame_calculos1,text="Forma   Exponencial",fg_color="#a3d9f3",text_color="black", hover_color="#FFFFFF",width=100)
    boton_exponencial.pack()
    boton_exponencial.place(x=345,y=50)
a= tk.Tk()
a.config(bg="#ffffff")
a.geometry("500x200")
frame=customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=a,fg_color="#f0f0f0", height=0)
frame.pack(pady=5, padx= 15, fill= "both", expand= True, )

label_cal=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master= frame, text="Elige el tipo de Calculo", font=("Arial",27),text_color="#000000")
label_cal.pack()
label_cal.place(x=90,y=10)
boton_op=customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame,text="Operaciones",command=operaciones,fg_color="#a3d9f3",text_color="black", hover_color="#FFFFFF")
boton_op.pack(pady=20, padx= 20, )
boton_op.place(x=240, y= 55)
boton_conver=customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame,text="Conversiones",command=convercion,fg_color="#a3d9f3",text_color="black", hover_color="#FFFFFF")
boton_conver.pack(pady=20, padx= 20)
boton_conver.place(x=70, y=55 )


a.resizable(0,0)
a.mainloop()

probe llamando al def con el global dentro de la función de esta manera
    global operaciones
    if operaciones.winfo_exists()==True:
        operaciones.destroy()


pero no funciono, entonces quiero saber de que forma puedo hacer esto con el winfo_exists o si hay otra manera

No entiendo que falla, ya que el cuerpo de la pregunta es ambiguo (que querés destruir?) Y el código no muestra el origen de la variable operaciones, que sería lo que hay que destruir. Podrías publicar un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable por favor? Además, te recomiendo revisar tu pregunta y explicar detenidamente el problema y el objetivo a alcanzar. También, en lo personal, recomiendo el buen uso de signos de puntuación, ya que, de otra manera, leo el texto como si hablaras rapido, y se entiende menos.

Lo primero de todo:
global operaciones
if operaciones.winfo_exists()==True:
    operaciones.destroy()

jamás va a funcionar porque operaciones en tu código es el nombre de una función, no un widget de tkinter, eso te generará una excepción del tipo:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'winfo_exists'

Para llamar al método winfo_exists() necesitas una referencia a un widget de tkinter, en este caso tu frame, como es el caso de la variable frame_calculos.
Segundo, winfo_exists() va retornar 1/True si el widget existe en el lado de TK/TCL (es decir, no se ha llamado a su método destroy()). No obstante siempre necesitaras una referencia del widget en el lado de Python, por lo que no es tan útil para lo que quieres hacer tu como es en el caso de Tk. Puedes llamar a winfo_exists() pero en realidad poco te aporta si tu finalidad es destruirlo si existe, esto se debe a que destroy() no te va a generar una excepción si la llamas sobre un widgets ya destruido previamente:
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk


def operaciones():
    global frame_calculos
    if frame_calculos is not None:
        frame_calculos.destroy()
        
    frame_calculos = ctk.CTkFrame(
        master=root,
        fg_color="#f0f0f0",
        height=350
    )
    frame_calculos.pack(pady=10, padx=15, fill="both", expand=True)
    entry_comple = ctk.CTkEntry(frame_calculos, border_color="#f0f0f0")
    entry_comple.pack()

    primer_num = ctk.CTkLabel(
        frame_calculos,
        text="Primer numero",
        text_color="#000000",
        font=("Arial", 22)
    )
    primer_num.pack()


def convercion():
    global frame_calculos
    if frame_calculos is not None:
        frame_calculos.destroy()

    frame_calculos = ctk.CTkFrame(
        master=root,
        fg_color="#f0f0f0",
        height=350
    )
    frame_calculos.pack(pady=10, padx=15, fill="both", expand=True)
    boton_exponencial = ctk.CTkButton(
        master=frame_calculos,
        text="Forma   Exponencial",
        fg_color="#a3d9f3",
        text_color="black",
        hover_color="#FFFFFF",
        width=100
    )
    boton_exponencial.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bg="#ffffff")
root.geometry("500x200")
select_calc_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root, fg_color="#f0f0f0", height=0)
select_calc_frame.pack(pady=5, padx=15)
frame_calculos = None

label_cal = ctk.CTkLabel(
    master=select_calc_frame,
    text="Elige el tipo de Calculo",
    font=("Arial", 27),
    text_color="#000000"
)
label_cal.pack()
boton_op = ctk.CTkButton(
    master=select_calc_frame,
    text="Operaciones",
    command=operaciones,
    fg_color="#a3d9f3",
    text_color="black",
    hover_color="#FFFFFF"
)
boton_op.pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=20, padx=20)
boton_conver = ctk.CTkButton(
    master=select_calc_frame, text="Conversiones",
    command=convercion,
    fg_color="#a3d9f3",
    text_color="black",
    hover_color="#FFFFFF"
)
boton_conver.pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=20, padx=20)

# root.resizable(0, 0)
root.mainloop()

Hay muchas más formas, por ejemplo, puedes limpiar el frame destruyendo todos sus hijos:
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk


def operaciones():
    for widget in frame_calculos.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    
    frame_calculos.pack(pady=10, padx=15, fill="both", expand=True)
    entry_comple = ctk.CTkEntry(frame_calculos, border_color="#f0f0f0")
    entry_comple.pack()

    primer_num = ctk.CTkLabel(
        frame_calculos,
        text="Primer numero",
        text_color="#000000",
        font=("Arial", 22)
    )
    primer_num.pack()


def convercion():
    for widget in frame_calculos.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    frame_calculos.pack(pady=10, padx=15, fill="both", expand=True)
    boton_exponencial = ctk.CTkButton(
        master=frame_calculos,
        text="Forma   Exponencial",
        fg_color="#a3d9f3",
        text_color="black",
        hover_color="#FFFFFF",
        width=100
    )
    boton_exponencial.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bg="#ffffff")
root.geometry("500x200")
select_calc_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root, fg_color="#f0f0f0", height=0)
select_calc_frame.pack(pady=5, padx=15)
frame_calculos = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root, fg_color="#f0f0f0", height=350)

label_cal = ctk.CTkLabel(
    master=select_calc_frame,
    text="Elige el tipo de Calculo",
    font=("Arial", 27),
    text_color="#000000"
)
label_cal.pack()
boton_op = ctk.CTkButton(
    master=select_calc_frame,
    text="Operaciones",
    command=operaciones,
    fg_color="#a3d9f3",
    text_color="black",
    hover_color="#FFFFFF"
)
boton_op.pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=20, padx=20)
boton_conver = ctk.CTkButton(
    master=select_calc_frame, text="Conversiones",
    command=convercion,
    fg_color="#a3d9f3",
    text_color="black",
    hover_color="#FFFFFF"
)
boton_conver.pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=20, padx=20)

# root.resizable(0, 0)
root.mainloop()

O si tus frames son muy diferentes, quizás sea más simple usar un frame contenedor externo y directamente destuir los frames:
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk


def operaciones():
    for widget in calculos_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    frame = ctk.CTkFrame(
        master=calculos_frame,
        fg_color="#f0f0f0",
        height=350
    )
    frame.pack(pady=10, padx=15, fill="both", expand=True)
    entry_comple = ctk.CTkEntry(frame, border_color="#f0f0f0")
    entry_comple.pack()

    primer_num = ctk.CTkLabel(
        frame,
        text="Primer numero",
        text_color="#000000",
        font=("Arial", 22)
    )
    primer_num.pack()


def convercion():
    for widget in calculos_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    frame = ctk.CTkFrame(
        master=calculos_frame,
        fg_color="#f0f0f0",
        height=350
    )
    frame.pack(pady=10, padx=15, fill="both", expand=True)
    boton_exponencial = ctk.CTkButton(
        master=frame,
        text="Forma   Exponencial",
        fg_color="#a3d9f3",
        text_color="black",
        hover_color="#FFFFFF",
        width=100
    )
    boton_exponencial.pack()



root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bg="#ffffff")
root.geometry("500x200")
select_calc_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root, fg_color="#f0f0f0", height=0)
select_calc_frame.pack(pady=5, padx=15)
calculos_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root, fg_color="#f0f0f0", height=0)
calculos_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True, pady=5, padx=15)

label_cal = ctk.CTkLabel(
    master=select_calc_frame,
    text="Elige el tipo de Calculo",
    font=("Arial", 27),
    text_color="#000000"
)
label_cal.pack()
boton_op = ctk.CTkButton(
    master=select_calc_frame,
    text="Operaciones",
    command=operaciones,
    fg_color="#a3d9f3",
    text_color="black",
    hover_color="#FFFFFF"
)
boton_op.pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=20, padx=20)
boton_conver = ctk.CTkButton(
    master=select_calc_frame, text="Conversiones",
    command=convercion,
    fg_color="#a3d9f3",
    text_color="black",
    hover_color="#FFFFFF"
)
boton_conver.pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=20, padx=20)

# root.resizable(0, 0)
root.mainloop()

También podrías no destruir los frames y simplemente usar forget() / forget_pack() / forget_grid() para ocultarlos y solo mostrar el correspondiente al botón pulsado. Esto te permite no tener que recrear todos los widgets y mantener el estado de los mismo, pero sin mostrarlos.

Por cierto, no se la razón, pero no uses distintos administradores de geometria (pack()/grid()/place()) sobre el mismo widget simultáneamente, me refiero que ahora mismo estas haciendo esto con muchos de tus widgets:
primer_num.pack()
primer_num.place(x=25, y=10)

usa uno de ellos según te convenga, no los dos.
